# Why Are The Fingers Attached On Some Cycling Gloves?

Tags: gloves

What is the purpose of the material connecting the fingers on some pairs of cycling gloves?

[image: Gloves with attached fingers]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's used to pull the gloves off without them going inside out. Don't pull too hard, or they will rip.  A gentle even pull should be enough to remove the gloves.

Comment: Yep, this allows the gloves to be removed without "stripping" them off.  "Stripping" (pulling from the wrist end and turning them inside-out) is recommended otherwise.  (To get them right-side-out put them on the wrong hands and "strip" them off again.)  If you pull off sweaty or wet gloves by tugging at the individual finger stubs it generally causes the stitching there to disintegrate fairly rapidly.

Comment: On some gloves there are little flaps at the fingers (look like tiny pockets). These serve the same function.